# Is Bisquick the same as self-rising flour?

Tags: flour

Is Bisquick the same thing as self-rising flour? or if not, what differences are there? Is it a good substitution if a recipe calls for self-rising flour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self rising flour consists of flour, salt, and baking powder.

Bisquick contains all of these ingredients *plus* hydrogenated vegetable shortening.

[Per Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisquick)

> One cup of Bisquick can be substituted by a mixture of one cup of flour, 1½ teaspoons of baking powder, ½ teaspoon of salt, and 1 tablespoon of oil or melted butter. Optional: to the above mixture add 1/2 cup buttermilk powder.

so while it is fairly easy to convert a recipe from using self rising flour to Bisquick (by also reducing the fat from the recipe), they are not quite a 1:1 substitution.